# Como género números aleatorios en formato octal y hexadecimal?

Tags: java

Como puedo hacer que se generen aleatoriamente números de formato octal y hexadecimal?

Answer (score 2):

Los números en formato octal y hexadecimal, son simplemente enteros expresados en base 8 (octal) o en base 16 (hexadecimal).

Para generar números aleatorios de este tipo, simplemente utiliza el método de `Random.nextInt()` de `Random` para generar enteros y luego los métodos estáticos `Integer.toOctalString` y `Integer.toHexString` para mostrarlos en su base correspondiente.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar [acá](https://onlinegdb.com/a6Rp2GMFtO):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100);

        var octal = Integer.toOctalString( randomNumber );
        var hex = Integer.toHexString( randomNumber );

        System.out.println("Numero en formato decimal: " + randomNumber);
        System.out.println("Numero en formato octal: " + octal);
        System.out.println("Numero en formato hexadecimal: " + hex);
    }
}
```